# Wordpress keeps adding auto paragraph tags to shortcodes and content

Tags: php, html, wordpress, shortcode

I can't seem to stop wordpress from auto adding paragraphs to every line I type, including shortcodes and any raw HTML I enter into the visual composer. I have tried the plugins "Toggle wpautop" and "Raw html" to try to convert it, however it never works. Is it because I'm using visual composer? It just wraps p tags around literally anything.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is not with Visual Composer, it happens purely because of the [`autop`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop) filter on [`the_content`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_content/). There are a few ways to tackle it, but IMHO a content filter is the best way to deal with it.

If you're comfortable editing your functions.php you can filter the `the_content` hook to remove `<p>` tags surrounding your shortcodes with [`strtr`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php) by adding the following:

```
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_unneeded_silly_p_tags_from_shortcodes');
function remove_unneeded_silly_p_tags_from_shortcodes($the_content){
    $array = array (
        '<p>['      => '[', //replace "<p>[" with "["
        ']</p>'     => ']', //replace "]</p>" with "]"
        ']<br />'   => ']' //replace "]<br />" with "]"
    );
    $the_content = strtr($the_content, $array); //replaces instances of the keys in the array with their values
    return $the_content;
}
```

The other alternatives ([*like removing autop from the_content*](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82889/93169)) tend to have pretty far reaching consequences, so I tend to avoid that. You could also try to remove margin stylings from that specific paragraph tag that gets added, but because of the auto-adding it may be difficult to target that particular tag...

Answer (score 1):

Try this, In your functions.php

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this issue for hours, and after many many tries I've found the problem.

My shortcode is getting content from a "Tinymce" custom-field. So in order to properly displaying it, I was using `apply_filters('the_content')` on the content. And Wordpress was adding the `<p></p>` to all following shortcodes in the current page, but not on the this shortcode (only if it is the first to be displayed).

The answer was to use only `wpautop()` to display this content.

It may be a hint for some.
Happy headache!!

Answer (score -1):

I modified @Frits answer. This tends to fix the very-annoying Google Chrome Mobile "Simplified View" nag that shows up at the bottom of your screen.

```
add_filter('the_content', 'remove_unneeded_silly_p_tags_from_shortcodes');
function remove_unneeded_silly_p_tags_from_shortcodes($the_content){
    $array = array (
        '<p>'      => '',
        '</p>'     => '<br /><br />'
    );
    $the_content = strtr($the_content, $array); //replaces instances of the keys in the array with their values
    return $the_content;
}
```

One problem with this, it removes any CSS style you added to the paragraph tags. But the benefit is clear: no Google Chrome Mobile nag!